# Подсчёт количества повторяющихся записей в базе MS SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть база данных клиентов и заказов на MS SQL Server. Нужно подсчитать, сколько заказов приходится на каждого клиента. Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT   
Table.fam ,--фамилия клиента  
count (table.idOrder) --номер заказа  
from Table  
group by Table.fam,table.idOrder
```

На выходе получаю

```
Попов   1  
Попов   1  
Попов   1  
Попов   1
```

А должно быть

```
Попов   4
```

Как это можно реализовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему у вас группировка по одному полю, а выводите другое? Будто в `p_fam` у четырёх Поповых разные данные лежат.

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce9985/12
```

Вот тут, вроде, всё как нужно.

**UPDATE**

Ну вот, теперь не нужна группировка по id, он же уникален:

```
SELECT
Table.fam
count (table.idOrder)
from Table
group by Table.fam
```

Comment: Я опечатался немного. Исправил, но все равно на выходе получаю по 4 фамилии в столбик и около них по 1, а не подсчет всех сразу.

Comment: @Andy92, обновил ответ.

Comment: убрал группировку по id и все заработало , спасибо большое !)

Comment: @Andy92, хорошо, но стоит обратить внимание на ответ ниже касательно однофамильцев. :)

Answer (score 4):

Довольно странно искать фамилии клиентов, а не их уникальные номера. Неужели в базе нет ни одного однофамильца? Что же касается вопроса:

```
SELECT [FAM], COUNT(FAM) as 'Количество'
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [FAM]
GO
```